# MPAndroidChart BubbleChart: single entry dataset ignores bubble size

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I have an array of 5: `float[] sizes` that will dynamically get values ranged 0-1.

I need to draw 0-5 bubbles (won't draw if size <0.5) with a different color each. Since we can specify color only at Dataset-level not entry-level, I have to use single-entry data sets.

Below is my code. The issue is, they are all of size 1, disregarding the size they got on the fly (0.9f, 0.8f, 0.7f...).

How to solve this problem?

```
private void initChart(){
    mChart = (BubbleChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    //mChart.setDescription("");
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(5);
    mChart.setPinchZoom(true);
    mChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.setDescription("");
    mChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinValue(-0.5f);
    mChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaxValue(5.5f);
}

private void updateChart(){
    ArrayList<IBubbleDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBubbleDataSet>();
    for(int i = 0, pos = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if(sizes[i] < 0.5f)
            continue;

        BubbleEntry entry = new BubbleEntry(pos++, 0, sizes[i]); //!!These sizes e.g. 0.9f, 0.7f ... are disregarded
        ArrayList<BubbleEntry> vals = new ArrayList<>();
        vals.add(entry);
        BubbleDataSet set = new BubbleDataSet(vals, "");
        set.setColor(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS[i], 130);
        set.setDrawValues(false);
        dataSets.add(set);
    }

    BubbleData data = new BubbleData(dataSets);
    data.setDrawValues(false);
    data.setHighlightCircleWidth(1.5f);
    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved. Add below line after new BubbleDataSet:

```
set.setNormalizeSizeEnabled(false);
```